# AngularJs cannot sort array even with javascript function

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, angularjs-orderby

**EDIT: I FIXED IT**

Well I fixed it, I don't know how and what but all I did is I moved the init of var personTaskMonthly=[]; from

```
$http.get().then(function(data){
var personTaskMonthly=[];})
```

to before the  $http starts
like this

```
var personTaskMonthly=[];
$http.get().then(function(data){})
```

Thank you all for helping me out on this problem.

EDIT:
I found out where the problem is, but I don't know how to fix that:
Everything seems to be fine till I execute the `$http.get().then(function(data){
/****** HERE I'm losing the correct order ****/});`
Its a complex code where I have 3 nested angular foreach functions.
And finally, somehow I get the desired results.
But the result is not sorted correctly and I don't know why.

This is the result:

```
{dayId: 1, dayName: "Jeudi", personTaskMonthly: Array(2), $$hashKey: "object:79"}

{dayId: 3, dayName: "Samedi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:82"}

{dayId: 2, dayName: "Vendredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:85"}

{dayId: 5, dayName: "Lundi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:88"}

{dayId: 6, dayName: "Mardi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:91"}

{dayId: 4, dayName: "Dimanche", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:94"}

{dayId: 10, dayName: "Samedi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:97"}

{dayId: 7, dayName: "Mercredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:100"}

{dayId: 12, dayName: "Lundi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:103"}

{dayId: 8, dayName: "Jeudi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:106"}

{dayId: 11, dayName: "Dimanche", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:109"}

{dayId: 9, dayName: "Vendredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:112"}

{dayId: 18, dayName: "Dimanche", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:115"}

{dayId: 13, dayName: "Mardi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:118"}

{dayId: 15, dayName: "Jeudi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:121"}
```

And My expected result is, something like this:

```
{dayId: 1, dayName: "Jeudi", personTaskMonthly: Array(2), $$hashKey: "object:79"}


{dayId: 2, dayName: "Vendredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:85"}


{dayId: 3, dayName: "Samedi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:82"}

{dayId: 4, dayName: "Dimanche", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:94"}

{dayId: 5, dayName: "Lundi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:88"}

{dayId: 6, dayName: "Mardi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:91"}


{dayId: 7, dayName: "Mercredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:100"}



{dayId: 8, dayName: "Jeudi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:106"}


{dayId: 9, dayName: "Vendredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:112"}

{dayId: 10, dayName: "Samedi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:97"}

{dayId: 11, dayName: "Dimanche", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:109"}

{dayId: 12, dayName: "Lundi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:103"}


{dayId: 13, dayName: "Mardi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:118"}

....
```

Can you help me please how do I sort this json result in order to achieve the desired thing?

this is my angularjs code:

```
function getMonthlyTask(daysInterv){
    /*
  var sDateHour = $scope.dayInterval[0].dsUnix;
    var eDateHour = $scope.dayInterval[$scope.dayInterval.length-1].deUnix;  */
    var taskPerDay=[];
    var i=0;
    var counter = [];


daysInterv.forEach(function(item, ind){

      var sDateHour = item.dsUnix;
        var eDateHour = item.deUnix;

      var dayName = item.dayName;
      var dId = item.id;

$http.get('link')
                .then(function(data){
                    var datas = data.data;
                    var personTaskMonthly=[];

                    datas.forEach(function(it, ind){
                      var idProfile = it.id_profile;
                      var idGroupe = it.id_groupe;

                      if (it.tasks){
                        var countPT = {};
                        var count;
                        it.tasks.forEach(function(k,v){

                            if(k.comptable==1){
                            if(!countPT[k.id_profile]){
                              count=1;
                              countPT[k.id_profile]=count;
                            }else{
                              count+=1;
                              countPT[k.id_profile]=count;
                            }
                           }

                        })
                        personTaskMonthly.push({'id_profile':it.id_profile, 'groupe':it.groupe,countPT});

                      }

                    })


                      taskPerDay.push({'dayId':dId,'dayName':dayName,personTaskMonthly});

                    //$scope.personTaskMonthly=personTaskMonthly;


                });//ending then



    })


        console.log(taskPerDay);
        var sorted = taskPerDay.sort(function(a,b){return a-b});
    $scope.taskPerDay = sorted;

    console.log(sorted);


  }
```

Comment: ok. but where is the code to sort it?

Comment: normally I should get this sorted already but something is happening and the sort is changing the order.

Comment: take a look at this link... Refresh it and you'll see that changes
http://thedev.koalito.com/newPlanning2/fullView.php

Comment: I'm not seeing the symptoms you are describing in the link you posted.

Answer (score 1):

Your sort function is using the whole object to compare you need to use as like
`taskPerDay.sort(function(a,b){ return a.dayId - b.dayId; })`

but alternatively you can use an angular 2/4/5 pipe to sort them in HTML code itself if you don't need the sorted array in javascript, there are lot of third party pipes available eg [ngx-order-pipe](https://github.com/VadimDez/ngx-order-pipe). If you are on Angular 1.x you can use the default [orderBy filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy) to do this for you

Comment: Hello.
Thank you for your help, I tried this also and it doesn't seems to fix the problem.
I always get the same result.

Answer (score 0):

In your sort() it's missing property dayId, try this

```
taskPerDay.sort(function(a,b){ return a.dayId - b.dayId; })
```

Comment: I tried this, and this won't work at all. I don't even know why

Comment: Maybe it's not an array, but an object instead?

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
var items = [{dayId: 1, dayName: "Jeudi", personTaskMonthly: Array(2), $$hashKey: "object:79"},

    {dayId: 3, dayName: "Samedi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:82"},

    {dayId: 2, dayName: "Vendredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:85"},

    {dayId: 5, dayName: "Lundi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:88"},

    {dayId: 6, dayName: "Mardi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:91"},

    {dayId: 4, dayName: "Dimanche", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:94"},

    {dayId: 10, dayName: "Samedi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:97"},

    {dayId: 7, dayName: "Mercredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:100"},

    {dayId: 12, dayName: "Lundi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:103"},

    {dayId: 8, dayName: "Jeudi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:106"},

    {dayId: 11, dayName: "Dimanche", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:109"},

    {dayId: 9, dayName: "Vendredi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:112"},

    {dayId: 18, dayName: "Dimanche", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:115"},

    {dayId: 13, dayName: "Mardi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:118"},

    {dayId: 15, dayName: "Jeudi", personTaskMonthly: Array(0), $$hashKey: "object:121"}]
    var sortedArray = items.sort(function(a,b){
     return a.dayId >b.dayId?1:a.dayId <b.dayId?-1:0
    })
    console.log(sortedArray);
```

updated and working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/7uwm8sd0/27/)

Comment: Your coul write this inside sort function ..return a.dayId >b.dayId?1:-1

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT: I FIXED IT**

Well I fixed it, I don't know how and what but all I did is I moved the init of var personTaskMonthly=[]; from

```
$http.get().then(function(data){
var personTaskMonthly=[];})
```

to before the  $http starts
like this

```
var personTaskMonthly=[];
$http.get().then(function(data){})
```

Thank you all for helping me out on this problem.